# Deploying a maven projects artefacts to our artefactory repository

Tags: maven

I have an artefactory repository, and a hudson integration server. These are working well together. For individual artefacts that are external dependencies I can deploy them successfully to the repository with something like this:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=ch.elca.el4j.services -DartifactId=xmlmerge -Dversion=2.0-SNAPSHOT-20100303 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jmodule-xml_merge-common-2.0-SNAPSHOT-20100303.jar -Durl=http://artifactory:8080/artifactory/repo -DrepositoryId=repo
```

However I cannot work out how to use deploy:deploy to upload a maven project's output (generated artefacts) into the repository in the same way that hudson is doing. I have tried (in the projects parent directory, where the pom is)

```
mvn deploy:deploy -Durl=http://artifactory:8080/artifactory/repo -DrepositoryId=repo
```

But it tries to deploy it to a Sonatype server and of course (thankfully) gets blocked

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mvn deploy:deploy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) does not take `url` as a parameter.  Instead it makes use of the information in the `<distributionManagement>` section of the pom to determine where to deploy.  Refer to [this usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) link for how to use this.